# How are contest problems designed?

Tags: soft-question, contest-math

How are competition questions designed? What techniques do designers employ to design math competition questions? How they know a problem can be solved by introductory methods?Some contest math questions involve the year of the contest as part of the question.
I think designing a math problem is as important as knowing how to solve it.

Comment: This might get closed. Perhaps you should rephrase it as a reference request to some article by a contest-math creator or something...

Comment: The people who are most qualified to answer this question (contest question designers) are unlikely to answer you. The rest of us can only guess.

Comment: In fact creating a big hypothesis is equivalently hard of solving it.

Comment: Some contest math questions involve the year of the contest as part of the question.

Comment: there is an article in one of the putnam books by bruce reznik who used to create questions for putnam.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203301/how-do-people-come-up-with-difficult-math-olympiad-questions?rq=1 and http://www.quora.com/How-do-people-come-up-with-math-olympiad-problems